# $e^{t\Delta }f $ grows at the same rate as $[\int f]G_t$ in $L_2$

Tags: fourier-analysis, regularity-theory-of-pdes

This is a question that I am asking to help myself with a homework question.
Assume $f$ has is smooth with compact support ( so that $f$ and $\hat f$ are in $\mathscr{S}$), and $G_t$ is the heat kernel.

A fourier approach seems the best way to go about this(because [see below] I am subtracting a first fourier coefficient) - so I am going to try to prove $L_2$ convergence.

That is for some constant $c$, $||\frac{e^{t \Delta}f}{[\int f] G_t(x)} - c||_2 \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Since $f$ has compact support this happens iff $||e^{x^2/4t} (\int e^{-(x-y)^2/4t}f(y))-c[\int f] ||_2 \to 0$.  Now replacing c by $C/(2\pi)^{d/2}$, we would like to take the fourier transform and use plancherel. Thus the above would tend to 0 iff (if the fourier transforms exist which they don't) $||\mathscr{F}[e^{x^2/4t}](\xi)* t^{d/2} e^{-|\xi|^2 t} - \hat f(0) ||_2$.  What we are seeing above is that the fourier transform $e^{x^2/4t} (\int e^{-(x-y)^2/4t}f(y))$ can't be written nicely as the convolution written above.  I need to do something different.  I am not sure how to get around this.

I think it is still reasonable to try to show $L_2$ convergence because this converges (by bounded convergence theorem)in $L_2^{loc}$ since  it happens pointwise when $f \in C^{\infty}_c$ before taking the fourier transform.

Do you have any ideas or hints?  Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the heat kernel *decay* over time? Not grow? Perhaps I'm not understanding the notation. What does $[\int f]G_t$ mean exactly?

Comment: the functions $1/n$ and $1/n+1/n^2$ both grow at the same rate because $lim \frac{1/n}{1/n+1/n^2}=1$.  Both functions do decay though.

Comment: Both functions do decay though.  $[\int f]G_t$ means $[\int f(y) dy] \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{d/2}} e^{-x^2/(4t)}$.

Comment: It's just weird terminology to me but I get it now.